# Excel VBA referencing .ListItem cells in separate userform

Tags: excel, reference, listbox, vba

I’m trying to use the cell contents in the selected row of a listbox to populate the labels in a separate userform when a command button adjacent to the listbox is clicked.  Using `“Listbox.List(.ListItem, 0)”` directly in the `“Caption”` property of a given label does nothing, not even throw up an error.  Reading the cell contents to a global array variable to elevate them to a scope wider than the userform containing the list box doesn’t work because for whatever reason global arrays aren’t kosher, and any permutation of the `.ListItem` property within the code for the result user form just returns a missing object error.  I don’t know what else to try.  How can I reference listbox cell contents in labels in separate userforms?

Comment: In the caption property? Like in the properties window? That's just going to change the caption at the top of your userform. Sounds like you need to place your code in a `Userform_Initialize()` sub. Maybe I'm mis-reading your question...

Comment: Can't get you. You have two Userforms?